# Powershell cannot cd to a path name with $

Tags: windows, powershell, environment-variables

In Windows Powershell, a command line `cd $HOME` leads to the Home directory. But a command line `cd $TEMP` or `cd $GOPATH` doesn't work, which returns `cd : Cannot process argument because the value of argument "path" is null.`

PS: The environment variables are configured.

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
GOPATH                         C:\Gowork
GOROOT                         C:\Program Files\Go\
TEMP                           C:\Users\myusername~1\AppData\Local\Temp
windir                         C:\Windows
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you meant the environment variable "temp", then you should do it as:

```
cd $env:temp
```

I think $HOME is some PowersShell specific variable, like $host, $ErrorActionPreference etc, while TEMP is a environment variable. Environment variables are read out as $env:VARIABLENAME.

I think gopath is also an environment variable of yours.

Comment: I get error messages trying to cd to PYTHONPATH (which contains spaces).

  cd $env:PYTHONPATH
returns
cd: nonconformal symbol in the path (the original message in French is :  
cd : Caractères non conformes dans le chemin d'accès.) 

On the other hand, the instruction
  echo $env:PYTHONPATH
works, returning
C:\"Program Files (x86)"\"Microsoft Visual Studio"\Shared\Python39_64  .

Attempting to 'cd' to this path (entered manually) also works.

I am trying to add the path to Python installed in Visual Studio to the system paths. Being capable to 'cd' would already help. Any hint?

Answer (score 1):

$HOME is an automatic variable.  You can see its value by entering it, by itself on the command line

You can see all current variables, including the automatic ones, by entering

```
Dir variable:*
```

You can read up on automatic variables here

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables

Comment: dir env:  works for me but dir variables:*     ?  that returns "Dir : Cannot find drive. A drive with the name 'variables' does not exist."

Comment: My mistake.  The provider is variable singular .  Edited.